# Reactivate Touchpad Two-Finger-Scroll on L430

Tags: lenovo, multi-touch, trackpoint

I'm just installing Ubuntu 12.10. on my ThinkPad L430 and the Trackpoint didn't work. So I executed the workaround

`echo "options psmouse proto=exps" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/trackpoint.conf`
and rebooted.

Unfortunately now the two-finger-scrolling on the touchpad doesn't work any more. But I'd prefer to use the touchpad scroll. Could anybody give me a hint, how to reactivate the two-finger-scroll and deactivate the trackpoint again.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer by myself. Delete the file `trackpoint.conf` and reboot.